# Ubuntu: default access mode (permissions) for users home dir (/home/user)

Tags: ubuntu, security, permissions, chmod, home-directory

What is a default access mode (e.g. 0755) for users home dirs in Ubuntu (e.g. what is output of `ls -ld /home/*`)? In other major linux distribs (Debian, RedHat, Gentoo, Arch)?

How can I change this default?

PS: Sorry, but I can't find an ubuntu now and test this myself.

Comment: I'm not asking about umask, but about `skel` and `home-dirs`

Comment: Please don't add new information in the comments, but include it in the original question

Comment: it is not a new info, it is comments about wrong understanding of my question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When creating a user using `useradd --create-home username`, the skeleton directory (usually `/etc/skel`) is copied, including its permissions.

The home directory (`/home/username`) is subject to the `UMASK` setting in `/etc/login.defs`. This is set to `022` by default, so the permissions for `/home/username` becomes 755.

Relevant excerpt from the [Ubuntu manual page of `useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/useradd.8.html):

> The following configuration variables in /etc/login.defs change the behavior of this tool:
>   [..]
>   UMASK (number)
>
> > The file mode creation mask is initialized to this value. If not specified, the mask will be initialized to 022.
> >
> > useradd and newusers use this mask to set the mode of the home directory they create

Comment: What about redhat/debian?

Comment: AFAIK it's a standard thing of `useradd`, if it would be Ubuntu-specific, it should have been mentioned in the manual page. A redhat manual page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

Comment: As of Ubuntu 22.04 it seems, `HOME_MODE` is now set in `/etc/login.defs` and is used to set the home directory (`/home/username`) permissions, instead of `UMASK`.

Answer (score 17):

Default permission of user home can be controlled in following places.

- The skeleton directory option (`-k, --skel SKEL_DIR`) of `useradd`.
- `SKEL` value in `/etc/adduser.conf` that define default skeleton directory.
- `DIR_MODE` value in `/etc/adduser.conf` that define default permissions.

Home directory of new users are created using `/etc/skel` as a template (default behavior).
Default permission of `/etc/skel` is `0755 (drwxr-xr-x)`.
Using a custom skeleton directory with correct permissions will allow new home directories to have desired permissions.

Defaults for `adduser` are defined in `/etc/adduser.conf`.
Default value of `DIR_MODE` in `/etc/adduser.conf` is `0755`.
Changing `DIR_MODE` to correct permissions (`DIR_MODE=0750` or similar) will allow new home directories to have desired permissions.
**According to Ubuntu documentation, this seems to be the best option.**

Already existing user home directories will need to be manually changed.

```
sudo chmod 0750 /home/username
```

So its a good idea to change `/etc/adduser.conf` right after the installation to avoid new users getting `0755 (drwxr-xr-x)` type permissions.
Still the very first user created during installation will have `0755` set to its home directory, which should be manually changed.

`UMASK` in `/etc/login.defs` is a general setting for files/directories/etc created by users (not only in their home directories). and could get changed depending on `USERGROUPS_ENAB` in `/etc/login.defs`.

The official explanation: [User Management - User Profile Security](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-users)
Check other sections of User Management as well.

Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46501/why-can-other-users-see-the-files-in-my-home-folder

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answers.

Comment: @techie007 I know. Would have used a comment if I had enough reps.

Comment: @techie007 Added more content to the answer

Comment: Setting `DIR_MODE` in `/etc/adduser.conf` is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Note : Don't change the **UMASK** value in **/etc/login.defs** if you want to change the home directory permissions only. Cause changing the UMASK will affect everything.

I once followed the same and when i installed any package system wide using pip it was not accessible to other users and was constantly throwing permission denied. Since the default **UMASK** affected the permission of all the package directories that got created after the changes were applied.

The correct way is to modify **DIR_MODE** in **/etc/adduser.conf**.  Since the **/etc/adduser.conf** is used in most linux distros so this solution works for most.

Answer (score 1):

The default permissions for /home in ubuntu is rwxr-xr-x or 755. For /home/user it is also rwxr-xr-x or 755. At least it is on my installation.

To change the file permissions of the home directory, open a terminal and run something like:

```
chmod 700 /home/user
```

Remember to change the 700 to the chmod value that you actually want to set.

If you do not own the directory, you need root privileges to change the permissions. Ubuntu uses `sudo` for that:

```
sudo chmod 700 /home/user
```

When you run this command it will ask for the administrator password.

Comment: Your second part is incorrect, the home directory is owned by yourself, so you won't need superuser right for that.

Comment: Your assuming he only wants to change the rights on his own home dir. I did say "If you do not own the directory." My code will work on the home dir of any user.

Comment: I edited your post to make it more correct (hopefully you like it), your original post did not include that at all: http://superuser.com/revisions/303995/1

Answer (score 0):

Check the [**umask**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/umask.1posix.html) man page.

The default umask setting is

```
0022
```

Allows `group` and `others` read and execute access.

Comment: No, My question is not about an umask, but about default permissions of user's folder itself (just after user `a` is created, what will be an output of `ls -ld /home/a`)

Answer (score 0):

Change `DIR_MODE=0755` to any other mode you want in `/etc/adduser.conf` eg. `DIR_MODE=0700`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).